# python: convert a number in scientific format to string

Tags: python

I have a series of numbers in the scientific format in a list:

```
A = [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4]
```

What I want to do is to change A into B:

```
B = ['1e-2','1e-3','1e-4']
```

I thought the conversion can be done by:

```
B = [str(A[ii]) for ii in range(len(A))]
```

But it gives:

```
B = ['0.01','0.001','0.0001']
```

Comment: `format(num, "e")` perhaps?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen That's pretty neat actually. However, I tried it myself, and it is outputting: `'1.000000e-02'`. Which, to me *is* the same, but not *exactly* as expected. Still, pretty darn awesome. Didn't know format did that for numbers expressed that way.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: can you be more specific of where to use the format function

Comment: if you want only one digit then do `".0e"` for 'no digits after the decimal', and it'd be used in the list comp: `[format(num, "e") for num in A]`

Comment: You don't have a series of numbers in scientific format. The scienctific format is just the string representation that you use to put in floats in a list. How the floats were formatted as string before converting to a float, the float doesn't know (nor does your program in retrievable way)

Comment: Here is what I wrote.

    A = [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4]
    B = [str('%.e' % i) for i in A]
    print(B)

output 

    ['1e-02', '1e-03', '1e-04']

Answer (score 3):

Try  `['{:.0e}'.format(float(x)) for x in A]`

Comment: You don't need `str.format`, and you don't need the `float` call. `[format(x, '.0e') for x in A]` works just as well.

Comment: @vaultah: Both are good solutions!! But yours are better!

Comment: I am getting `'1e-02'` instead of `'1e-2'`, is there a way to eliminate the 0 in the `02` part ?